# Iterate javascript map

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a simple javascript map which does not contain identifiers for the fields. I can iterate through the map but can not obtain the values without the field identifiers.

```
var processStatusTypes = {
       1:'ClaimProcess Status 1',
       2:'ClaimProcess Status 2',
       3:'ClaimProcess Status 3',
       4:'ClaimProcess Status 4',
       5:'ClaimProcess Status 5',
       6:'ClaimProcess Status 6',
       7:'ClaimProcess Status 7'
};

for (var index in processStatusTypes) {
    console.log(processStatusTypes[index][0]);
    console.log(processStatusTypes[index][1]);
}
```

I know this should be simple but i can not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You just need `processStatusTypes[index]`, It a simple object with primitive values. What exactly you need?

Comment: I don't think that's a real "map" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map What I see here, is just a regular object.

Comment: processStatusTypes[index] will fetch the value of key indexed by 'index' and processStatusTypes[index][0] will fetch first character of value of key indexed by 'index', so to get values just specify processStatusTypes[index]

Comment: @Satpal processStatusTypes[index] just gives the whole element at index, not the individual key and value.

Comment: @Ahmet, `index` is key in this scenario. Just test `console.log(index, processStatusTypes[index]);`

Comment: @Satpal index is the value of my loop; it is under my control. However keys of the map are different than the loop index. Besides processStatusTypes[index] gives whole key-value pair like "1:'ClaimProcess Status 1'". I just want to access key and value separately without correlating loop index and key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var processStatusTypes = {
       1:'ClaimProcess Status 1',
       2:'ClaimProcess Status 2',
       3:'ClaimProcess Status 3',
       4:'ClaimProcess Status 4',
       5:'ClaimProcess Status 5',
       6:'ClaimProcess Status 6',
       7:'ClaimProcess Status 7'
};

var keys = Object.keys(processStatusTypes);
for (var i = 0;i<keys.length;i++) {
    console.log(keys[i], processStatusTypes[keys[i]]);
}
```